Reducing extreme behavior in linear-exponential decay hybrid function
I am writing data reduction software for residual gas analysis mass spectrometry in Python. One of the primary goals of this software is to fit measured gas intensities $y$ back to the gas equilibration time $t=0$ to determine the theoretical equilibrated intensity, $y_0$.
I am currently struggling with fitting an exponential-linear equation to describe gas consumption:
$$y = a \exp(-pt) + bt + c$$
where:

$y$ is the dependent variable, intensity in A
$t$ is the independent variable, time after $t=0$
$a$, $b$, $c$, and $p$ are fitted parameters

NOTE THAT THIS MODEL HAS BEEN REPLACED BY A 'PLAIN' EXPONENTIAL MODEL. This is discussed in the edits below.
Here are some examples of "good" consumption curve fits:

in which the data are:
Mass 2 amu y: [1.03151253e-10 1.02764656e-10 1.00429739e-10 9.97269907e-11
 9.89678330e-11 9.94845128e-11 9.73211157e-11 9.67399363e-11
 9.69838881e-11 9.57109351e-11 9.54086215e-11 9.57198459e-11
 9.54274476e-11 9.59283426e-11 9.53714218e-11 9.29636333e-11
 9.44152076e-11 9.35152455e-11 9.32533980e-11 9.30672260e-11]
Mass 2 amu t: [  7.028  14.238  21.45   28.667  35.874  43.077  50.384  57.389  64.593
  71.901  79.01   86.215  93.419 100.627 107.831 115.035 122.243 129.354
 136.657 143.768]

Mass 3 amu y: [3.29778253e-10 3.26265256e-10 3.20505639e-10 3.16877521e-10
 3.16086483e-10 3.13754743e-10 3.11454306e-10 3.09359856e-10
 3.08538478e-10 3.06927955e-10 3.05987101e-10 3.03379296e-10
 3.00944658e-10 3.02971263e-10 3.01609542e-10 2.99715203e-10
 2.99172588e-10 2.97572855e-10 2.97728968e-10 2.97632036e-10]
Mass 3 amu t: [  8.116  15.326  22.538  29.755  36.962  44.165  51.472  58.477  65.681
  72.989  80.098  87.303  94.507 101.715 108.919 116.123 123.331 130.442
 137.745 144.856]

and some examples of non-physical or unrealistic "over" fitting:

Mass 2 amu y: [8.92991171e-11 8.76522093e-11 8.61052948e-11 8.70397469e-11
 8.71706708e-11 8.68983223e-11 8.70813401e-11 8.68469981e-11
 8.60065722e-11 8.68007260e-11 8.69227029e-11 8.73408691e-11
 8.64896431e-11 8.70329228e-11 8.60186671e-11 8.62989490e-11
 8.67176164e-11 8.59189454e-11 8.64824077e-11 8.64498292e-11]
Mass 2 amu t: [  3.529  10.636  17.841  25.047  32.259  39.469  46.676  53.882  60.986
  68.191  75.399  82.611  89.816  97.023 104.226 111.335 118.54  125.745
 132.95  140.157]

or worse, like this:

Mass 2 amu y: [9.37982279e-11 9.12279184e-11 9.11408812e-11 9.16890908e-11
 9.11226495e-11 9.11011735e-11 9.09514699e-11 9.17458313e-11
 9.07343618e-11 9.07010068e-11 8.98410055e-11 9.09835375e-11
 9.19705903e-11 9.08708285e-11 9.18843137e-11 9.03661067e-11
 8.99796615e-11 9.12228596e-11 9.02898722e-11 9.06567840e-11]
Mass 2 amu t: [  5.326  12.433  19.639  26.849  34.058  41.267  48.475  55.577  62.782
  69.987  77.294  84.496  91.7    98.909 106.022 113.129 120.335 127.54
 134.861 141.971]

What I am looking for is a technique that can mitigate this extreme exponential behavior that is not:
a. arbitrary. That is, I can enforce what looks like reasonable boundaries on $a$, limiting the extreme behavior. Unless, however, that boundary is physically informed (an impossibility), this is "drawing" rather than math; if I can "draw" the intercept wherever I want within a reasonable range, this is not a real solution to finding the intercept.
b. iterative. I'm aware of techniques like resampling/bootstrapping which mitigate the effects of a single outlier on the fit, however, each sequence is composed of dozens to hundreds of analyses, each with four intensity curves that need fitted. Iterating to convergence for every fit of every analysis would likely take too long.
Is there a technique out there that addresses the problem of extreme fitting without sacrificing statistical rigor but which also doesn't require tens of thousands of iterations for each fit? If not, what are my best bets for a relatively quick iterative solution?
EDIT:
Comments below have pointed out that the model may be over-parameterized, or that the linear and exponential components are collinear. So, let's instead test a simpler exponential decay model, dropping the linear term:
$$y = a \exp(-pt) + b$$
First 'bad' example:

The bad part of the fit is essentially unchanged.
Second 'bad' example:

This is a significant improvement, but still what I'd consider a bad fit. In both cases, the first datum or data are overly influential.
Let's take a look at some additional examples of the pure exponential decay function:

Mass 2 amu y: [1.11548579e-10 1.08525584e-10 1.08637585e-10 1.07313054e-10
 1.07505906e-10 1.09903448e-10 1.07406689e-10 1.07287881e-10
 1.09239799e-10 1.08388794e-10 1.08434548e-10 1.09562372e-10
 1.08491898e-10 1.07433321e-10 1.07241049e-10 1.07906125e-10
 1.07342845e-10 1.08231794e-10 1.06374158e-10 1.08389173e-10]
Mass 2 amu t: [  7.824  15.031  22.239  29.445  36.653  43.858  50.967  58.175  65.379
  72.589  79.794  86.901  94.108 101.316 108.524 115.827 123.031 130.137
 137.341 144.551]

A fourth and final bad example:

Mass 2 amu y: [1.21722448e-10 1.18559989e-10 1.19321282e-10 1.18560030e-10
 1.17919157e-10 1.17473574e-10 1.17322868e-10 1.17165008e-10
 1.16127572e-10 1.13762917e-10 1.14853700e-10 1.15794776e-10
 1.14554932e-10 1.13071377e-10 1.14009997e-10 1.14744161e-10
 1.15094138e-10 1.13814270e-10 1.14155051e-10 1.13944753e-10]
Mass 2 amu t: [  1.498   8.707  15.911  23.123  30.331  37.441  44.649  51.855  59.06
  66.263  73.471  80.675  87.785  94.992 102.196 109.402 116.71  123.918
 131.028 138.235]

My question remains unchanged: how can I limit the extreme behavior or reduce the influence of overly influential low-$t$ data without either "eyeballing" some regularization factor or adding excessive iteration time?
EDIT2:
I have added errors (dominated by a standard error of 0.35%) and furthermore switched to an algorithm that uses the lowest predicted $p$ value of three lmfit algorithms: 'leastsq', 'nelder', 'lbfgsb'. I am still experiencing overfitting:

40 amu y: [1.00801174e-11 8.60445782e-12 8.74340722e-12 9.63923122e-12
 8.77654502e-12 8.83196162e-12 9.44882502e-12 9.54364002e-12
 8.68107792e-12 9.19894162e-12 9.26220982e-12 9.30683432e-12]
40 amu y_err: [3.55155742e-14 3.03603530e-14 3.08456363e-14 3.39750319e-14
 3.09613755e-14 3.11549311e-14 3.33097888e-14 3.36410485e-14
 3.06279460e-14 3.24368170e-14 3.26578373e-14 3.28137314e-14]
40 amu t: [13.489 19.117 24.829 30.433 35.939 41.645 47.253 52.883 58.585 64.292
 69.698 75.408]


40 amu y: [1.02342173e-11 9.13542299e-12 8.71434679e-12 9.30896839e-12
 9.67921739e-12 8.81455689e-12 9.01517339e-12 9.32982869e-12
 9.07950499e-12 9.10221369e-12 9.13479289e-12 9.74699459e-12]
40 amu y_err: [3.60428801e-14 3.22023916e-14 3.07310036e-14 3.28088823e-14
 3.41029042e-14 3.10811524e-14 3.17821748e-14 3.28817853e-14
 3.20069819e-14 3.20863388e-14 3.22001897e-14 3.43398009e-14]
40 amu t: [ 9.808 15.54  21.056 26.757 32.365 37.967 43.603 49.221 54.934 60.453
 66.158 71.669]


4 amu y: [1.93881406e-11 1.92799499e-11 1.93063737e-11 1.92661388e-11
 1.93331621e-11 1.92483915e-11 1.92890094e-11 1.93013490e-11
 1.92584063e-11 1.92694922e-11 1.92188237e-11 1.92390129e-11]
4 amu y_err: [6.79677264e-14 6.75896709e-14 6.76820041e-14 6.75414107e-14
 6.77756118e-14 6.74793963e-14 6.76213277e-14 6.76644462e-14
 6.75143910e-14 6.75531285e-14 6.73760780e-14 6.74466248e-14]
4 amu t: [ 9.202 14.715 20.422 25.93  31.632 37.267 42.895 48.495 54.122 59.834
 65.443 71.044]

EDIT3:
I am also having similar problems with the exponential "ingrowth" equation (that is, ingrowth in the context of desorption of gases from the walls of a vacuum system):
$$
y = a\left(1-\exp(-pt)\right) + y_0
$$
Examples:

2 amu popt: [ 0.3909168  -1.25301047  1.55414465]
2 amu p init: -0.02807382661291184 p: 1.5541446549605047
2 amu y: [1.94081413 1.94488608 1.94299664 1.94320119 1.94695494 1.94557881
 1.94542436 1.94399005 1.9451058  1.94547516 1.94491979 1.94713906]
2 amu y_err: [0.00679303 0.00680728 0.00680067 0.00680138 0.00681452 0.00680971
 0.00680916 0.00680414 0.00680805 0.00680934 0.0068074  0.00681517]
2 amu t: [ 3.609  9.218 14.826 20.435 26.256 31.76  37.467 42.975 48.68  54.288
 59.897 65.607]


40 amu popt: [ 1.77297540e+00 -3.44720554e-01  1.16543687e-16]
40 amu p init: -0.07021559537682079 p: 1.165436867291928e-16
40 amu y: [1.7272498  1.77756104 1.76045714 1.76518087 1.7744118  1.75588506
 1.75636136 1.77632841 1.75749027 1.76967936 1.81365046 1.79016038]
40 amu y_err: [0.00607652 0.00625224 0.0061925  0.006209   0.00624124 0.00617653
 0.0061782  0.00624793 0.00618214 0.00622471 0.0063783  0.00629625]
40 amu t: [10.73  16.349 21.957 27.663 33.165 38.879 44.385 50.101 55.804 61.314
 67.043 72.644]

EDIT4: One answer below questions the methodology used to find the given fits. I will share this below.
        try:
            if self.use_int_errs:
                self.popt, self.pcov = curve_fit(self.fitting_function, self.t, self.y, sigma=self.y_err, absolute_sigma=True, bounds=self.boundaries, p0=self.init_guess)
            else:
                self.popt, self.pcov = curve_fit(self.fitting_function, self.t, self.y, bounds=self.boundaries, p0=self.init_guess)
        except RuntimeError:
            self.popt = np.zeros_like(self.init_guess)
            self.pcov = np.zeros((len(self.init_guess), len(self.init_guess)))

The try/except block sets all parameters to zero if the convergence fails. Then, I calculate the AIC of the model approach vs the average approach:
                if all(self.popt == 0):
                    model_aic = np.inf
                else:
                    model_pred_y = self.fitting_function(self.t, *self.popt)
                    model_resids = (self.y - model_pred_y) / self.y_err if self.use_int_errs else self.y - model_pred_y
                    model_aic    = self.calculate_aic(len(self.popt), model_resids, len(self.t))
                
                if self.use_int_errs:
                    avg_pred_y, avg_pred_y_err = weighted_average_and_error(self.y, self.y_err)
                else:
                    avg_pred_y = np.mean(self.y)
                    avg_pred_y_err = np.std(self.y) / np.sqrt(len(self.y))
                avg_resids = (self.y - avg_pred_y) / self.y_err if self.use_int_errs else self.y - avg_pred_y
                avg_aic    = self.calculate_aic(1, avg_resids, len(self.t))

in which
    def calculate_aic(self, n_params: int, residuals, n_points: int):
        """Calculate the Akaike Information Criterion (AIC) for a given fit

        Args:
            n_params (int): number of parameters in the model
            residuals (_type_): residuals from the fit
            n_points (int): number of data points
        """
        rss = np.sum(residuals ** 2)
        return n_points * np.log(rss / n_points) + 2 * n_params

The approach with the lowest AIC is used.

It looks like the data are being fitted fairly closely. In which case it seems to be more  of a regularization / prior knowledge issue.

Do you need this particular functional form? Or will a reliable extrapolation to time 0 be adequate?

@EdM My program contains several different means of extrapolating to $t=0$, but most of them fall short when fitting gas consumption curves due to the fact that it's actually an exponential (or exponential-linear) decay function.

I forgot to complete my thought before finishing my comment... that is, I would prefer to have some form of an exponential decay function, but if you have other suggestions for similar forms, I'd be open to hearing them.

It might make sense to examine convergence characteristics of the models as a first step to identifying data sets that are too noisy for a 4-parameter fit based on only about 20 time points. There seems to be no problem with your first 2 examples, and it's possible that your third example really is OK. For your last example, however, I've gotten non-convergence warnings with the nls() function in R, even after playing with parameter choices. Maybe you need a two-stage approach: an initial attempt with your parametric model and some type of smoothed extrapolation when that is inadequate.

Also consider whether there are inherent physical constraints on some of the model parameters, in particular the exponential decay rate. Your last two examples seem to show very large decay rates. Or you could penalize the magnitude of the decay-rate coefficient, although that could lead to bias given the inherent bias-variance tradeoff.

As far as placing constraints, this is impossible to do in a physically-informed way. Any constraints I place would be guesses at best and therefore be resorting to "drawing, not math." As for the convergence, I haven't seen any non-convergent warnings in Python (scipy.optimize.curve_fit), but it wouldn't surprise me. I implemented a filter similar to your suggestion just yesterday which checks the linear R^2 and, if below 0.3, foregoes the fitting for taking the bulk average. This needs improved by checking the R^2 of the actual model, however.

In the two bad cases your model is indeterminate because the exponential part and the linear part are essentially collinear.  We had to ask the same set of questions in your previous version of this question, which involved the same issues, so I won't go over mine again, but will only request you consult the comments there for advice.

@whuber simplifying the model down to $y = a \exp(-pt) + b$ still yields overfitting. I will post examples.

Could you explain in what respect that is "overfit"?  I suspect you aren't using that term in a conventional sense.

Your suspicion is correct and I apologize for not being more explicit. While I acknowledge that these are the OLS fits to the data, what I really care about is the intercept, which should be informed by the entire data trend, not just the placement of a few low-$t$ not-quite-outlier data. I feel the algorithm is weighting those few initial data far too highly and ignoring the rest of the trend, causing the fit to behave in a "non-physical" manner and producing an invalid intercept.

You might be getting to the crux of the matter concerning "weighting." The right way to weight depends (primarily) on the errors in your measurements.  What can you tell us about them, especially their distributions and whether they are independent?

To be honest, I do not calculate or apply errors in $y$ at the moment because the true errors are unknown to me, however, prompted by this, I have reached out to the MS manufacturer to shed some light on this. Whatever the errors are, they are not independent. My guess is that they grow as the intensity approaches zero.

Therein might lie one resolution to your question.

This sent me down a deep rabbit hole, out of which I emerged with an estimation of the errors as $$\sigma_y = \sqrt{\sigma_b^2 + \frac{yq}{t_\text{dwell}}}$$ where $q$ is the charge of an electron, $\sigma_b$ is the variance in the baseline aka noise, and $t_\text{dwell}$ is the dwell time of the analysis. This combines the Gaussian baseline noise with the Poisson-distributed MS detector counting statistics. Unsurprisingly, the errors are invisibly small for most reasonably high intensities and do not change the fitting routines significantly.

My newest idea to solve this problem is to literally run the program, grab the $p$ value from at least 100 different analyses with reasonable fits, take the average and variance of those values, and use them as Bayesian priors to guide the fitting routines. I don't know enough about statistics to know whether this is a valid approach, though.

Without knowing what is the non-linear regression method and the numerical calculus you used to compute and draw your graphs it is difficult to determine the cause of the failures that you mention.
One guess is that the initial values of the parameters to start the iterative process are not good enough.
An unusual method which is not iterative and which doesn't need initial values is shown in https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales
Using this method in your two problematic cases the results are shown below :


You may try to put in your software the above values $p$ , $a$ , $b$ , $c$ as initial values for the iterative method.
IN ADDITION AFTER OP's COMMENT :
In comment ohshitgorillas asked about explicit application to his equation model of the method refreed above. The algorithm is :

Note : In interrest of numerical calculus accuracy one could rescale the data in case of very small order of magnitude. For example multiplying $y_k$ by $10^{11}$ in the above example. This doesn't change $p$ but the computed $a,b,c$ have to be multiplied by $10^{-11}$.
IN ADDITION after new ohshitgorillas's request :

IN ADDITION : An example of comparison of results ( In one of your so-called "bad cases ):


Thanks for your response! The two fits from your "unusual" method look better than mine, however, changing the initial parameters was not effective at yielding different fits. Perhaps you could be more explicit about the technique that you're using to achieve those parameters? I do not speak French and therefore have a difficult time parsing your paper.

@ohshitgorillas. The algorithm is added to my main answer.

I have marked this answer as the solution. Even though it did not resolve the issues with the exponential-linear model originally proposed in the question, it does resolve the issues with the normal exponential decay model proposed in the edit to the question. And besides, the fact that your fitted $b$ parameter goes to zero is suggestive that the linear term was invalid anyway. Thank you.

Of course the fitted $b$ is not equal to zero in all casses but only in particular cases. In fact it isn't exactly equal to zero but very small and out of range of accuracy of numerical calculus. The data is highly scattered thus a small term in the model equation becomes without signifiance.

Would you mind supplying the initial guess calculus for the simpler decay equation $y = a \exp(-pt) + b$ as well?

This is added at end of my main answer. Symbols are different on this older available document.

While this has been effective at reducing some behaviors, it has not totally eliminated the behavior. I am editing the main question to reflect this.

I have re-selected this as the answer. While the original suggestion to use the predicted value of $p$ as an initial guess was unsuccessful in preventing all overfitting, using it directly and only allowing for optimization of $a$ and $b$ does work.

The softwares for non-linear regression uses various algorithms and the initial guess might be more or less convenient depending on the iterative process. I cannot say what append in your case. Another way to check : In case of large scatter of the data the result of non-linear regression depends on your chosen criteria of fitting (or on the criteria of fitting implemented in the software). I suppose that this is LMSE. You should try LMSRE (least mean square relative error) or others.

I'm not sure that I understand your recommendation, can you please rephrase? I have implemented a Bayesian Information Criteria check to determine whether the bulk average or the curve fitting is more appropriate, so in cases of very high scatter, the program now defaults to using the average of the measured intensities rather than the curve fitting results.

Forget my preceeding comment about criteriaof fitting. I made a few tests. The change of criteria of fitting doesn't change much the results.

In comparing your results to my results ( with an  iterative method only ) I observed that your results and my results are rather different especialy in the so called "bad examples". One of this kind of comparison is added at the end of my main answer. This draw me to think that something might be fishy or wrong in the iterative method of regression that you use. Could you check the same examples with a different software than the software that you use.

This is interesting. For reference, I am using curve_fit from SciPy. I am trying lmfit now but getting the same results. Not exactly different software, but practically I need to solve this problem in Python. I will explore some other fitting functions as well.

As an aside, perhaps it would be possible to use the initial guess of $p$ and its variance as some sort of Bayesian prior knowledge?

Would it be appropriate to ask for the "initial guess" solutions for the equation $$y=a / (1-\exp(-t/p)) + b$$ as well?

$y=a/(1-exp(-t/p))+b$ tends to infinity when $t$ tends to $0.$ This seems not consistent with the data.

Sorry, the equation is $$y = a(1-\exp(-pt)) + b$$. That was my mistake.

$$y=a(1-\exp(-pt))+b=A\exp(-pt)+B$$
You know how to compute $A$ and $B$. Then $a=-A$ and $b=B+A$.

I open another answer because the question was modified. This new answer is for the exponential equation without linear term.
From your EDIT2 first example of data.
I cannot reproduce your calculus and the result of my calculus is very different from your result.
In my result there is no anomaly in the area where you get a bad fitting.
My extrapolated value $y(0)\simeq 9.29*10^{-12}$ appears rather satisfactory.

This draw me to think that there is something wrong in your calculus and/or in the software that you use (Maybe not convergence of the iterative process).
ADDITION after ohshitgorillas's request in comment :
Details of numerical calculus ( MathCad software. Screen copy).

Of course one can try to improve the fitting with post-treatment using a software for nonlinear regression. This works well in many cases but not in all cases depending on the software used for post-treament.
If the result after post-treatment is worse than the result without post-treatment let us not beat about the bush. This means that the bad result is due to the post-treatment not due to the equation model and/or scatter. This means that the tool used for post-treatment and the algorithm implemented into it failed.
Failure of nonlinear regression calculus can be due to many causes such as not convergence, convergence to local "optimum" instead of to the whole optimum, numerical computation failure due to bad rounding and others. In order to solve this kind problem one have to ask the creator of the software. Only him knows exacly what his software is doing and how the software was built to be convenient to a majority of cases (but it is never convenient for all cases).
NOTE FOR INFORMATION :
In the method of fitting used above with MathCad the criteria of fitting is not the classical Least Mean Square regression wrt $y$ but is the Least Mean Square regression wrt a linear integral equation to which $y$ is solution. In the case of $y=a+b\,e^{cx}$ the integral equation is
$$y=c\int y\:dx+a\,c\,x+\text{constant}$$

May you please share your exact methodology for producing the displayed fit? What software, fitting function, etc?

I have added my curve fitting code/method to the question.

Details of my calculus are added an the end of my answer and information about the sothware.

It's bad when multiple answers to vanished versions of a question accumulate in a thread.  When a question is modified enough to require a different answer, please ask the OP to roll it back to the original and start a new question.  If they don't respond, flag the thread for moderator attention.

I am posting an independent answer because the "solution" to these problems was complex. I am leaving JJacquelin's answer with the linearized problem marked as the solution, however, it was only part of the solution.
I am able to "domesticate" the exponential function by:

Using the initial guesses provided by JJacquelin above.
Using the Aikake Information Criteria to determine whether the exponential curve is actually appropriate for the data. If it's not, we use the bulk average of all intensities instead.
Imposing empirical limits by taking the $p$ value from over 150 subjectively 'good' measurements and using the mean - 3$\sigma$ as a hard limit. That is, $0 > p > \bar{p}_\text{good} - 3\sigma_{p_\text{good}}$.

Given these three approaches, I am no longer seeing non-physical exponential consumption/ingrowth rates. That said, if anyone sees room for improvement, I am open to it.
